# How does Go update third-party packages?

Tags: go

Looking how actively golang packages grow and improve I wonder how the problem with package versions is solved?

I see that one way is to store third-party packages under a project folder.

But what if I install it with `go get`?

Answer (score 401, accepted):

`go get` will install the package in the first directory listed at `GOPATH` (an environment variable which might contain a colon separated list of directories). You can use `go get -u` to update existing packages.

You can also use `go get -u all` to update all packages in your `GOPATH`

For larger projects, it might be reasonable to create different GOPATHs for each project, so that updating a library in project A wont cause issues in project B.

Type `go help gopath` to find out more about the `GOPATH` environment variable.

Comment: is it possible to update all packages to latest version, kind of like bundle update?

Comment: should just be `go get -u all`

sorry to resurrect, but just in case anyone else was looking.

Comment: `go get -u all` no longer works! Running this command in the GOPATH, at least for Go 1.13, will return a warning: `warning "all" matched no packages"

Comment: Works with Go 1.12.9

Comment: Go 1.16.3, `go get -u all` doesn't work. Is there a replacement?

Answer (score 103):

@tux answer is great, just wanted to add that you can use [go get](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies) to update a specific package:

```
go get -u full_package_name
```

Comment: For updating a specific branch of the package: go get -u full_package_name.BRANCH_NAME

Answer (score 25):

Since the question mentioned ***third-party*** libraries and not ***all*** packages then you probably want to fall back to using wildcards.

A use case being: I just want to update all my packages that are obtained from the Github VCS, then you would just say:

```
go get -u github.com/... // ('...' being the wildcard).
```

This would go ahead and only update your github packages in the current `$GOPATH`

Same applies for within a VCS too, say you want to only upgrade all the packages from ogranizaiton A's repo's since as they have released a hotfix you depend on:

```
go get -u github.com/orgA/...
```

Answer (score 14):

The above answeres have the following problems:

1. They update everything including your app (in case you have uncommitted changes).
2. They updated packages you may have already removed from your project but are already on your disk.

To avoid these, do the following:

1. Delete the 3rd party folders that you want to update.
2. go to your app folder and run `go get -d`

Answer (score 11):

To specify versions, or commits:

```
go get -u otherpackage@1.2.3

go get -u otherpackage@git-sha
```

See https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#daily-workflow

Answer (score 6):

Since this is one of the top hits when googling, I just wanted to add that for 1.17 "installing executables with 'go get' in module mode is deprecated".

- `go get -d`

  - For dependencies of the current module
- `go install`

  - For requirements of the current module
- `go install <with_version>`

  - To install ignoring the current module, i.e: 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'

https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation

Answer (score 4):

go 1.13

(exec from module root directory)

Update specified dependencies:

```sh
go get -u <package-name>
```

Update all direct and indirect dependencies to latest minor or patch upgrades (pre-releases are ignored):

```sh
go get -u ./...
# or
go get -u=patch ./...
```

Reference:

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#daily-workflow

`go help get`

Comment: What is the actual difference between `go get -u` and `go get -u ./...`
In theory it should be the same but in practice `go get -u ./...` recursively updates all the dependencies of dependencies (major versions) in my project and can cause a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to upgrade a version from a specific branch, you can use:

```
go get -u <path-to-repo>@<branch>
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to path and type

```
go get -u ./...
```

It will update all require packages.

Comment: This literal interpretation does not work. Some more context would be helpful.

Comment: I do believe he meant `go get -u ./...` (3 dots)

Comment: `go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.`