# Golang auto completion nsf package

Tags: autocomplete, go

I have installed sublime and go.

Tried the autocompletion feature offered by https://github.com/nsf/gocode.

It works perfectly for standard packages.

But not working for external packages like the ones fetched from github.

Any help on this appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to set `GOPATH` _before_ starting sublime or set `GOPATH` in the project folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will only work if you build and install those external packages.

if you just `go get` their sources, the completion won't work, even said sources are in the `GOPATH/src/...`.

Those packages need to be at least compiled (`GOPATH/pkg`).

As mentioned in "[How does Go update third-party packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383783/6309)", a `go get -u all` can help.

Comment: I used the command go install og all my github external code. Found object files created at GOPATH/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com. Set the GOPATH and GOROOT path too. Restarted the sublime text. But still it is not working. Am I going wrong anywhere.

Comment: @Pals I don't use gocode, only gosublime (https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime), and the completion does work once an external library is (`go install`) installed.

Answer (score 0):

For go autocomplete to work (Atom Editor, Sublime, even vim with autocomplete)

1. Your package must be placed in the go path. (this can be automatically done if the project is on github and you use the get tool)

   ```
    go get -u github.com/username/packageName
   ```
2. you must build your package

   ```
    go build $GOPATH/pathToYourProject...
   ```
3. you must install your package

   ```
    go install $GOPATH/pathToYourProject...
   ```