# Failed to install

Tags: linux, go, unix, terminal

I was trying to install gospider and other tools,I get this error

```
sudo go get -u github.com/jaeles-project/gospider
```

```
../../go/src/github.com/jaeles-project/gospider/core/crawler.go:28:20: unknown field 'MaxConnsPerHost' in struct literal of type http.Transport
../../go/src/github.com/jaeles-project/gospider/core/crawler.go:184:21: undefined: strings.ReplaceAll
../../go/src/github.com/jaeles-project/gospider/core/crawler.go:297:35: undefined: strings.ReplaceAll
../../go/src/github.com/jaeles-project/gospider/core/linkfinder.go:14:12: undefined: strings.ReplaceAll
../../go/src/github.com/jaeles-project/gospider/core/linkfinder.go:15:12: undefined: strings.ReplaceAll
```

I tried to update
`sudo go get -u all` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383498/how-does-go-update-third-party-packages) but it runs forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `strings.ReplaceAll` is undefined that means you're using a version of Go prior to 1.12, which is when that function was added.

To install that package, you need to first update your Go version to something after 1.12 (ideally the latest version).